# how to get an image in jersey rest web service

Tags: java, android

My listBo class

public class ListBO {

```
public String itemName = "";

public String itemType = "";

public String itemImg = "";

public String itemPrice = "";

public int itemId;

    /**
     * @return the itemName
     */

public String getItemName() {

return itemName;

}
    /**
     * @param itemName the itemName to set
     */

public void setItemName(String itemName) {

this.itemName = itemName;

}
    /**
     * @return the itemType
     */

public String getItemType() {

return itemType;

}
    /**
     * @param itemType the itemType to set
     */

public void setItemType(String itemType) {

this.itemType = itemType;

}
    /**
     * @return the itemImg
     */

public String getItemImg() {

return itemImg;

}
    /**
     * @param itemImg the itemImg to set
     */

public void setItemImg(String itemImg) {

this.itemImg = itemImg;

}

public void setItemId(int itemId) {

this.itemId = itemId;

}

public String getItemPrice(){

return itemPrice;


}

public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {

this.itemPrice = itemPrice;

}

My listjson class

@Path("/listItems")

public class ListJson {         


@Path("/lists")

@POST

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public List<ListBO> getList(){

System.out.println("Called Main JSON");

List<ListBO> lists = new ArrayList<ListBO>();


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


ListBO items = new ListBO();


items.setItemId(i);


items.setItemName("Chicken :"+i);


items.setItemType("Type :"+i);


items.setItemPrice("Price :"+i);


if(i<=10){


items.setItemPrice("20");


}


lists.add(items);           



}


return lists;
```

}

i can add image like this but it doesnot return an image please helpme..

/*@Path("/image") class ImageService {

private static final String FILE_PATH = "c:\images.jpg";

@GET

@Path("/get")

@Produces("image/jpg")

public Response getFile() {

File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);

response.header("Content-Disposition",

"attachment; filename=image_from_server.jpg");

return response.build();

}

}   */

}

how to return an image and where can i store an image give me an example..

Answer (score 1):

you can't return an image in a JSON object. JSON is not meant for binary data. your web service should return JSON containing a field that is a reference to the image, a URL. then the code that consumes the web service must get the URL from the JSON and fetch the image from the URL.

```
{ imageUrl: "http://foo.com/image.png" }
```

it's hard to say exactly what you are doing without more information. you also might want to re-tag this as jersey or resteasy, not android. i *think* the code you posted is a jersey resource, looking at the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

use the [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/implementation) for send image in the rest web service.

Comment: BSON is a way to serialize binary data. while both JSON and BSON store key, value pairs, that is where the similarity ends. they aren't compatible and they don't inter-operate. moreover, BSON is essentially relegated to use in MongoDB and is not generally accepted as a standard in the way JSON is.